# How to switch between red and blue colours using clickEventListener using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

First, I am creating two functions Blue and red.

```js
function drawBlueCircle(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(mouse.x,mouse.y,50,0,Math.PI *2)
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawRedCircle(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(mouse.x,mouse.y,50,0,Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Here I am creating a clickEventListener with `if` statements in For loops

```js
canvas.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    mouse.x = event.x,
    mouse.y = event.y
    
    for(let i=0;i<event.length;i++){
        
        (i%2==0)? drawBlueCircle():drawRedCircle() // here i am trying to alter my clicks using for loops. 
    }
})
```

My error is :
even after clicking my mouse, it stays red.This red I have through other `eventListener` mousemove but that's not the problem .

P.S.: this is not the Entire code. I have given only the one I couldn't solve(above).

I tried above code and I couldn't change color.

Comment: You will need to track the state yourself, there's no `event.length` property that tracks how many times a click has occurred. The easy option is to just invert a boolean variable each time you click, and use that to pick a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a loop you should maintain a reference to the next colour to be drawn. In addition if you pass in the colour (along with the context, and the event) as a function argument you can reduce your functions to one: `drawCircle`, and use that colour to determine the circle's fill colour.

```js
// Pass in the context, event, and colour to the
// function so you can use them
function drawCircle(ctx, event, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(event.x, event.y, 50, 0, Math.PI *2);
  ctx.fill();
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Initialise the color
let color = 'red';

canvas.addEventListener('click', event => {
  
  // Draw a circle with the current colour
  drawCircle(ctx, event, color);

  // Switch the color
  color = color === 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red';
});
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help ! but i have been trying to understand the line  drawCircle(ctx,event,color) here i couldnt understand! can you please explain

Comment: It calls `drawCircle` with three arguments. The first is the canvas context which we defined just before the listener. The second is the event - we pass that into the function so we can access its `x` and `y` properties, just like you were doing with `mouse.x = event.x`. The third is the colour - and we use that for the fill colour in the function. Basically it makes the function interface clearer about what it should be accepting to do its job rather on rely on global variables. And it makes it easier to test.

Comment: Thank you very much that was short and simple !

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is just to have a boolean variable storing your expected colour, and then invert it each time you click:

```js
function drawBlueCircle() {
  console.log('drawBlueCircle called')
}

function drawRedCircle() {
  console.log('drawRedCircle called')
}

// This variable tracks which color we are up to
let isBlue = true

// Added the listener to 'window' for the sake of the example
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // Run the expected function
  if (isBlue) {
    drawBlueCircle()
  } else {
    drawRedCircle()
  }
  
  // Invert the next color
  isBlue = !isBlue
})
```

```html
Click anywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do, from what I understand , is toggle between `drawRed` and `drawBlue` with each click.

The reason, I think, your code isn't working is because essentially every time you click, that for loop is run. After the loop is run, either `drawBlue` or `drawRed` is 'selected', meaning, only one of them is run. And it will give the same result every time (because, for whatever reason, you're running a loop through the event object).

What you can try to do is have a boolean flag set outside the `addEventListener`. Then, in the callback function, you can fire either `drawBlueCircle` or `drawRedCircle` based on this boolean flag. After that you can toggle its value.

Something like this :

```
let isRed = false;

  canvas.addEventListener('click',function(event){
      mouse.x = event.x;
      mouse.y = event.y;

    if(isRed){
      drawRedCircle()
    }
    else {
    drawBlueCircle()
    }

    isRed = !isRed;
})
```